Azure CLI run-command invoke runshellscript - How to get output of shell script
I am running a command in an azure pipeline
az vm run-command invoke --command-id RunShellScript --name DevServer -g Takeoffs --scripts "cd /home/user/workdir/project/ && bash ./buildDev.sh > /home/user/workdir/project/exlogs.txt"

This shell script has different exit codes for different errors.
I would like to be able to catch them.
It sounds like the output I can catch is the output of the "az vm run-command invoke", but the exit codes of the actual shell script are lost.
How can I actually get the exit code?
I tried getting the command output with something like this:
command_output=$(az vm run-command invoke --command-id RunShellScript --name AIDevServer -g Takeoffs --scripts "cd /home/aiadmin/workdir/wall_classification/ && bash ./buildDev.sh > /home/aiadmin/workdir/wall_classification/exlogs.txt" -o json)
echo "Command output: $command_output"

But this only gives the output of the az vm run-command command, and not the underlying shell script exit code.

I did something else to work around this issue, my script now creates different files in the cloud, so I can check the files and see what happened without checking the exit code.

You can add a new answer to share the workaround to solve the issue.  Then you can accept the answer. This will be helpful to other users who has the same issue

Well it's not really useful. It's just me giving up on the exit codes and having to program a sort of communication system through files to figure out what exit my script took.

Yes. So the root cause of this problem is that az vm run-command invoke does not support returning exit codes, as stated in my answer. You can give feedback in the github post mentioned in the answer

I can reproduce the same situation. When using the command: az vm run-command invoke, it only shows the command result message without the exit code.
For example:

This is a limitation from the azure cli itself.
I am afraid that the az vm run-command invoke command doesn't support output the exit code of the command result.
Here is a suggestion ticket in Github: Support exit code reporting in az run-command invoke You can monitor the suggestion ticket and add comment to share your ideas.
For a workaround, you can use SSH task in azure pipeline to run the shell script in Azure VM.
It will use SSH to connect to Azure VM to run a shell script. And you can see the exit code.
For example:
- task: SSH@0
  inputs:
    sshEndpoint: 'test0405ssh'
    runOptions: 'inline'
    inline: |
      cd /home/aiadmin/workdir/wall_classification/ && bash ./buildDev.sh > /home/aiadmin/workdir/wall_classification/exlogs.txt
      echo $?
    readyTimeout: '20000'

Result:

